# ¿Como comprobar que el nodo no existe firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

¿Como puedo comprobar si existe el nombre en la database usuarios?

Con este código puedo ver que el usuario existe pero cuando la variable `user` cambia a otro usuario no obtengo ningún error.

```
var user = 'Moises';
firebase.database().ref('usuarios').orderByChild('usuario').equalTo(user).on('child_added', function(data) {
  console.log('user exist');
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Solución @Marcos:

```
firebase.database().ref('usuarios').orderByChild('usuario').equalTo(user).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.exists() ? 'user exist' : 'user non existent');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El parámetro `data` es un [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), por lo que si quisieras validar si el mismo **no existe**, deberias usar [`exists`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists)

### Ejemplo:

```
var user = 'Moises';
firebase.database()
 .ref('usuarios')
 .orderByChild('usuario')
 .equalTo(user)
 .on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.exists() ? 'user exist' : 'user non existent');
   }, function(error) {
     console.log(error);
   });
```

Comment: En consola no muestra ningun log a mi parecer no entra en el ON()

Comment: @jsstoni, prueba cambiando `.on('child_added'` por [.`on('value'`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#on)

Comment: Gracias Marcos funciona dejo la solución

Comment: @jsstoni, puedes responder tu propia pregunta, por lo que te recomiendo crees una respuesta. Después de 2 días vas a poder marcarla como la acertada.